# How to send an ehlo test e-mail from calibre?

Tags: email, hostname, smtp, calibre, epub

An excerpt from a failed test e-mail in `calibre`

```
Starting job: Email book to fake6546565345@kindle.com 
connect: to ('smtp.ionos.com', 587) None 
reply: b'220 perfora.net (mreueus004) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready\r\n' 
reply: retcode (220); Msg: b'perfora.net (mreueus004) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready' 
connect: b'perfora.net (mreueus004) Nemesis ESMTP Service ready' 
send: 'ehlo mordor.foo.bar.com \r\n'
```

I've modified the `@kindle.com` com address for privacy in the first line, and in the last line, am using `foo` and `bar` as well.  Otherwise, it's a precise excerpt.

Using the old `pine` client, now known as `alpine`, the settings are:

```
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ cat .pinerc | head -n 30 | tail -n 10

# List of SMTP servers for sending mail. If blank: Unix Alpine uses sendmail.
smtp-server=smtp.ionos.com:587/tls/user=foo@bar.com

# NNTP server for posting news. Also sets news-collections for news reading.
nntp-server=

# Path of (local or remote) INBOX, e.g. ={mail.somewhere.edu}inbox
# Normal Unix default is the local INBOX (usually /var/spool/mail/$USER).
inbox-path={imap.ionos.com:993/ssl/user=foo@bar.com}INBOX
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ hostname
mordor
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
nicholas@mordor:~$ 
nicholas@mordor:~$ calibre --version
calibre (calibre 5.37)
nicholas@mordor:~$
```

From the `calibre` an `ehlo` test is being sent to `foo@mordor.bar.com` whereas it should be being sent to `foo@bar.com` as specified.  While I've not included a screenshot, the settings for `calibre` don't include the hostname above.

Why is `calibre` using the local machine's `hostname` for the `FQDN` of the `SMTP` server when no such setting has been explicitly set?

(It doesn't have to be a test e-mail, sending actual `epub` files generates similar errors.  Just looking to send `epubs` with `calibre` but looking at the test e-mail to determine what the [problem](https://www.mobileread.com/forums/showthread.php?p=4285078#post4285078) is.)